# Command of an item from the title bar into onCreate | Android

Tags: android, titlebar

Does anybody knows how to put the code of an item from the titlebar into the onCreate?

The code is still so:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.layout1);

    // Here the code of the item should be

}


// But it's here:
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main3, menu);
    return true;

}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.item1) {

        // Command

        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Thanks for help!

Comment: What you want to do? Please be specific.

Comment: I mean that I want to put the code for the command of the item in the onCreate because the code deals with variables of the onCreate and when I write the code in the onOptionsItemSelected, then there is the error "Cannot resolve symbol"

Comment: Then you have to create global variable if you want to use in onOptionsItemSelected.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I found it out by myself. But your answer was correct! :)

Comment: Pleasure is all mine :)